# What was the initial price of the Sharp X68000?

Tags: cost

I can't seem to find out what the Sharp X68000 cost when it first available.  Is there a reliable source for this information?

I'm looking for actual sales costs of a standard X68000 unit (preferably without monitor and accessories) when it was available.

Comment: [These](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=eT4xBmc6iYM) [ads](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E4M0YNfRZCM) also show pricing information. Are you looking for a catalog, or real prices *e.g.* in a dealer’s ad in a magazine?

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm looking for real pricing.  I'm looking to do a price/performance analysis on this computer vs. other computers of the time.  Thanks!

Comment: @cbmeeks how is the 369 number not "real pricing"?

Comment: @WillHartung the 369 number does qualify.  Stephen Kitt asked me if I was looking for catalog pricing or "real prices" so I answered his question by saying I'm looking for real pricing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These might not qualify as authoritative, but they do claim to be based on the original X68000 catalogs (over a few years):

- [The Giant Bomb page on the X68000](https://www.giantbomb.com/sharp-x68000/3045-95/) says it launched at 369,000¥, approximately $2,500 (US) at the time;
- [GameSX has a price list](https://gamesx.com/wiki/doku.php?id=x68000:x68000_product_catalog) which confirms this figure.

Two adverts show pricing information:

- [an ad for the first X68000 model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eT4xBmc6iYM), repeating the 369,000¥ figure;
- [an ad for the Expert HD and Pro models](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E4M0YNfRZCM), with prices matching the GameSX list.

Comment: That isn’t true. 370,000 yen back in March 1987 was about $2,500 according to this website: https://www.poundsterlinglive.com/bank-of-england-spot/historical-spot-exchange-rates/usd/USD-to-JPY-1987 That is roughly equivalent to $5,500 in today’s dollar.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I’ve updated my answer. Would you mind updating the wiki page? That’s where the information came from.